# Check an element inside a node - XML, C#

Tags: c#, xml

I need to check if the element (w:position) exists in the (w:rPr) node and in the other siblings of this parent node (w:r)

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
    <w:color w:val="231F20" />
    <w:w w:val="108" />
    <w:position w:val="7" />
    <w:sz w:val="12" /></w:rPr>
    <w:t>3</w:t>
</w:r>
```

So far here's my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlfile);

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("w:r");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");

foreach (XmlNode node in elemList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.SelectSingleNode("//w:position", nsmgr).OuterXml);
}
```

Once I confirm that the element exist in the node, I need then to select the other child w:t to get it's inner text.

This xml is a snippet from "document.xml" of MS Word. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the problem with your given code?

Comment: Do you have to use `XmlDocument` rather than LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc)? The latter is a much better API in my view - and handles namespaces really cleanly.

Comment: @GiladGreen I want to get an if statement working inside the foreach loop saying that I've found the w:position element inside the selected node.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, no LINQ to XML here. Could you give an example using LINQ to XML? Appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow - are you saying an answer using LINQ to XML will work for you or not? Or is that just for the sake of interest?